# Any reason to make private methods in a Spring singleton bean static?

Tags: java, spring, performance, singleton, static-methods

I did some research but didn't find an answer that I am looking for. In Spring, DAO and service classes are declared as interface. Classes implementing interfaces are usually singleton Java beans. Question: do you see any reason that I should make private methods that don’t rely on instance variables static? Why?
For example, I have several private methods in a DAO class converting database data to domain object and these private methods don’t use instance variables. I understand some people might suggest that I should extract them to a utility.

Comment: as a rule of thumb sou should use the `static` key word only if you have a *good reason* to do so. Avoid instantiation is *not* such good reason...

Comment: it's better to not use static methods. There's only 1 instance anyway, and Spring works much better with nonstatic code. There's no performance impact, and creating objects is extremely cheap and fast. Only concern yourself with object creation after creating 'many' (million plus?) objects, but only after measuring.

Comment: When using a DI framework there is no point in using static methods. Statics ate evil for anything but very simple utility methods.

Comment: @Erik: Could you elaborate why Spring works much better with non-static code? I am referring to a private method in a singleton Spring bean. So we won't create many objects. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @user3123690 well, that changes the question a bit, but it hardly matters to have static methods. Maybe your colleague insists because IntelliJ recommends doing that, but I see no reason. Then again, I also see hardly reason to have private methods at all.

Comment: .@Erik The reason we create private methods because people manually set length limits on a method(check style)

Answer (score 3):

The word *singleton* is used in multiple ways, which can cause a bit of confusion. A "hard" (physical, class-based, JVM) singleton is a class that ensures that only one instance can exist in the entire JVM, usually through an enum or a constant. This pattern should be avoided if the object has any state or configuration at all, since that can cause unexpected coupling between parts of an application. (It's usually fine if the object represents either a pure function, such as `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`, or a value.)

In contrast, a singleton-scoped bean (logical, container-based) simply means that the container that is managing it will keep a single shared instance and supply it to all consumers that want one (instead of, for example, creating a separate private copy for each consumer). In most Spring applications, it's actually preferred for these to implement a Java interface that serves as the contract between the two sides, so the methods *can't* be static.

As to performance questions, `static` carries a *meaning*--specifically, that the method or field doesn't have a relationship to a specific instance of that class. Use it when *the meaning* is appropriate (such as most of the methods in `Math`), and don't change the meaning of your code in this way for any theoretical performance reason.